# Как данные вернуть в формате json?

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

Всем привет! Есть форма по поиску (использую без `ajax`). Результат показывает в норме. Решил применить `ajax` и `json`. Вопрос: как данные вернуть в формате `json`, в документации немного запутался...

Как сейчас отправляю:

```
 def dictfetchall(cursor):
   desc = cursor.description
   return [dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))for row in cursor.fetchall()]

 if request.GET['searchType'] == 'FIO':
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
            cursor.execute(sql2.format(request.GET.get('search','').encode("utf-8")))
            return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'forms': SearchForm(), 'res': dictfetchall(cursor)})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое простое решение, «в лоб»:

```
…
data = {"res": dictfetchall(cursor)}

# Если в адресе было «?json» (или «?json=1»), значит отдаем JSON.
if request.GET.get("ajax", None) is not None:
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res), content_type="application/json")
else:
    data["forms"] = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response("search/search.html", data)
```

(`HttpResponse` в `django.http`)

Если такого надо много и часто — стоит задуматься о генерализации, например в духе чего-то такого декоратора:

```
def template_or_json(template_name):
    def __decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def __wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            data = f(request, *args, **kwargs)

            if request.GET.get("json", None) is not None:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
            else:
                return render_to_response(template_name, data,
                                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        return __wrapper
    return __decorator
```

И далее

```
@template_or_json("search/search.html")
def my_view(request):
   ...
   return {"res": dictfetchall(cursor)}
```

(В коде возможны несущественные опечатки или описки, пишу на память, не проверял.)

Comment: Данные не приходят в json.

Comment: А поконкретнее, пожалуйста? Как их запрашиваете и что получаете? Должно быть, например, как-то так (вариант на голом jQuery):

    $.getJSON("...?json=1", function (data) {
        console.log(data.res);
    });

Да, и я сейчас заметил ошибку, поправил декоратор. Если использовался вариант с ним — я там `json.dumps` забыл.

Comment: Вижу что пришел ajax, но данные я получаю в get и отправить нужно их в формате json. Может в терминологии немного ошибаюсь т.к. с ajax и json и к ним прилегающими плюшками первый раз...)

Comment: Скрипт не вошел сюда, отправил тебе лично в vk.

Comment: (Скопировал тут: http://pastebin.com/R0TkyB5h)

Выглядит правильно, а что приходит? Ошибка (alert) или что в консоли? `HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), ...)` должно отдать JSON'ину. Можно поменять `content_type="text/plain"` да открыть URL прямо в браузере (мимо `$.ajax` и посмотреть что так).

Comment: Я просто запутался, вижу в meta:
'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'
GET:<QueryDict: {u'search': [u'10.3.5.60'], u'searchType': [u'IP']}>
Все данные приходят на сервер, до отправки данных еще не дошло до меня как их отправлять.

Comment: Ну так, повторяясь:

1. Добавить в URL в `$.ajax` "?json". Т.е. "/test/?json". Чтобы отличить запрос. И во вьюшке `request.GET.get("json", None) is not None` выявляем это.

2. Сформировать данные (словарик с чем там надо) и `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(переменная))`.

3. Вроде бы, собственно, и все.